# RAM upgrade compatibility?

Tags: memory, upgrade, dell-latitude

I bought myself a RAM memory upgrade. Specifically (Corsair Ddr3 8gb 1600mhz Cmso8gx3m1b1600c1). My laptop is Dell Lattitude E6440. Would it fit? Been reading that my laptop takes ddr3L, but this is just ddr3. Just noticed it :7. So will it even work? I heard the main difference is voltage, right?

Thanks,
EB.

Comment: It looks like so-dim memory so it should work as long as it will work with the voltage that your laptop supplies.

Comment: I do not think it will work because the latitude e6440 requires 1.5v ram and as far as I can tel, the RAM you ordered is 1.5v only.

Comment: Nope, apparently the RAM  installed runs on 1.35V. And I think the one I bought is 1.5V. So my guessing it will overheat? Or will it even recognize it?

Comment: It appears like you purchased desktop DDR3 memory instead of laptop DDR3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell Latitude E6440 Laptop supports 2 x 8GB max. Supports only DDR3L ( Low-voltage DDR3 @ 1.35v). Regular DDR3 (1.5v) is unsupported.

CMSO8GX3M1B1600C1 is Standard DDR3, will not work with Latitude E6440

Refer this link for the Dell Latitude E6440 Laptop RAM:

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/DellLatitudeE6440.html

Manual: http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/latitude-e6440-laptop_owner's%20manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: Guess you are right on the voltage. But maximum capacity is 16GB as shown in the manual. I suppose I will need to get another one.

Comment: Yes, mentioned 2 x 8GB = 16GB max.